# Password is never valid - Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to build custom login functionality for an API, I'm trying to achieve this using tokens but I'm running into some problems. It always says password not valid so the password valid condition never turns to true for some reason even if the password is valid, Here is my code:

```
class UserTokenHandler(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        username = request.GET['username']
        password = request.GET['password']
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if user.exists():
            if User.objects.get(username=username).password == password:
                chosen_token = ''
                for i in range(20):
                    lower_case = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
                    numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
                    upper_case = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
                    random_choice = random.randint(1,3)
                    if random_choice == 1:
                        chosen_token += lower_case[random.randint(0, len(list) -1)]
                    elif random_choice == 2:
                        chosen_token += numbers[random.randint(0, len(list) -1)]
                    elif random_choice == 3:
                        chosen_token += upper_case[random.randint(0, len(list) -1)]
                token = UserLogin.objects.create(token=chosen_token, user=user)
                token.save()
                print(password)
                print(username)
                return Response({'Token': chosen_token})
            else:
                print(password)
                print(username)
                return Response({'Error':'Invalid Password'})
```

Comment: Isn't your stored password encrypted?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, How can I decrypt the stored password?

Comment: Passwords are not stored as plain text in the database (At least if you properly use Django's authentication system). They are **hashed**. So writing `User.objects.get(username=username).password == password` would not work. Also I said in your previous question use [TokenAuthentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) provided by Django Rest Framework instead of doing so much work

Comment: I am not able to use the built in functionality since my project needs custom fields and some functionality which the built in one does not have.

Comment: Hopefully they are stored encrypted and you can't decrypt them. You need to hash the one entered by the user and compare that to the stored encrypted one.

Comment: How can I hash the user input?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser7 and how does that stop you from using `TokenAuthentication` (honestly your implementation is bad, you also send the credentials as GET parameters which I again repeat is **insecure**).

Comment: Yeah, I know its insecure but this will be used as a backend which the user will not be able to interact with. The user will only be able to interact with frontend which is React and only my React server would be authenticated to send requests to backend

Comment: That stops me from using the built in one because i need to have multiple models and fields in certain situation or functionality, I'll try to use built in one if this does not work

Comment: "_only my React server would be authenticated to send requests to backend_" is not a valid reason to send credentials in a GET request. There could be anyone listening in / sniffing the users network and find out their credentials. their ISP, Any routers in the path taken by the packet, **anyone** could get their credentials. Use a **POST** request it is not that hard to do that. Also what you said does not in any way  prevent you from using `TokenAuthentication` in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use check_password method for check password because password is encrypted

**Note:** It is better to use the POST method for important information like password because GET method show password in URL

```
class UserTokenHandler(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        username = request.GET['username']
        password = request.GET['password']
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if user.exists():
            if User.objects.get(username=username).check_password(password):
                chosen_token = ''
                for i in range(20):
                    lower_case = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
                    numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
                    upper_case = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
                    random_choice = random.randint(1,3)
                    if random_choice == 1:
                        chosen_token += lower_case[random.randint(0, len(list) -1)]
                    elif random_choice == 2:
                        chosen_token += numbers[random.randint(0, len(list) -1)]
                    elif random_choice == 3:
                        chosen_token += upper_case[random.randint(0, len(list) -1)]
                token = UserLogin.objects.create(token=chosen_token, user=user)
                token.save()
                print(password)
                print(username)
                return Response({'Token': chosen_token})
            else:
                print(password)
                print(username)
                return Response({'Error':'Invalid Password'})
```